# Defaulting my app's file extension in VS-2013 to open with my app

Tags: file-extension

So I was making my application in Visual Studio 2013 (Visual Basic), when I found out that I cant open my saved file (Document) with my application. It says: "Windows cannot open this file." My file was saved using a save file dialog, and the extension is ".asef" - plz help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is. Maybe this will help
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/630ed1d9-73f1-4cc0-bc84-04f29cffc13b/what-registry-keys-are-responsible-for-file-extension-association?forum=netfxbcl